# Can I set "Treat all wireless networks as public" before i even connect to one

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, script, netsh

When connecting to a Wireless network in a fresh Windows 7 installation you are treated to the following:

[image: Set Network Location]

Is there a way to tell Windows not to ever display this notification and treat all networks as public by default. perhaps in local Group Policy or Local Security policy. I've had a look but can't see anything.

Another way round the problem would be to specify the type of network when adding it from a script.
We currently use a .bat file containing the following:

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="filename.xml"
netsh wlan connect wirelessname
```

If there is a way to specify the type of network location in Netsh - I don't think there is - then this would solve the problem also.

**Edit:** I'm looking to avoid **Any** user interaction in this. I want something that can be set before syspreping or run as a command on first logon.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to just check that little box at the bottom 'Treat all future networks that I connect to as public, and don't ask me again.' You can also get to this screen from the 'Network and Sharing Center' as shown from the screenshot below.

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

This solution is much less complicated than trying to cook up a script to do it.

Another possibility, in case the 'Public Network' isn't clickable, is to modify a registry key. The one of interest is this:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NetworkLocationWizard\
REG_DWORD key: HideWizard
```

From there you can modify or delete that key as you see fit.

Comment: But it still requires connecting to a wireless and user interaction which is exactly what I'm looking to avoid. That registry key may be more promising.

Comment: Modifying the registry key to 1 will disable this screen and treat all networks as public. Excluding networks that are predefined i.e. Domain networks connected in WDS deployment which is absolutely perfect. Thanks for the tip, I confirmed it using RegShot - http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Registry-Tweak/Reg-Shot.shtml